# How can I create groups out of this data set?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.2

I have a table as follows:

```
   id    | similar_id|
 --------+-----------+
    1    |     2     |
    1    |     3     |
    2    |     1     |
    2    |     3     |
    3    |     1     |
    3    |     2     |
    4    |     5     |
    5    |     4     |
```

How can I write an optimised sql query such that I can find similar groups?

i.e., Group1 -> {1,2,3}, Group2 -> {4,5}

P.S., I understand that the data could have been organised better.

Comment: What should be the result if the table contains also the row: (5, 1) ?

Comment: For now, lets assume that the table contains no such entries

Comment: I think your problem requires a complex algorithm, and cannot be solved with a unique (even if complex), SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct (
    select array_agg(a order by a)
    from unnest(a) a(a)
) as "group"
from (
    select id || array_agg(similar_id) a
    from t
    group by id
) s
order by 1
;
  group  
---------
 {1,2,3}
 {4,5}
```

From this data:

```
create table t (id int, similar_id int);
insert into t (id, similar_id) values
(1,2),
(1,3),
(2,1),
(2,3),
(3,1),
(3,2),
(4,5),
(5,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple plain SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT groups
FROM (
  SELECT id, array_agg(similar_id) groups
  FROM (
    SELECT id, similar_id
    FROM grp
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT id, id
    FROM grp
    ORDER BY 1, 2) subsub
  GROUP BY 1) sub
ORDER BY 1;
```

This will produce:

```
 groups 
---------
 {1,2,3} 
 {4,5}
```

The trick here is to use the `UNION` such that every `id` is paired with itself and it's `similar_id`s and then it is simply a question of aggregating.